# TextBox with Error Template with code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, adorner, errortemplate

I'm trying to add some textbox to a form by code, not XAML. And using Error Validation. I have the following code:

```
SearchTextBox stb = new SearchTextBox()
{
    Name = "stbRelatorio_" + id
};

// Create a new Binding.
Binding bindingStb = new Binding();
bindingStb.Source = model;
bindingStb.Path = new PropertyPath("ReportFile[" + id + "]");
stb.SetBinding(SearchTextBox.FileNameProprety, bindingStb);

BindingExpression bindingExpression =
    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(stb, SearchTextBox.FileNameProprety);

BindingExpressionBase bindingExpressionBase =
    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(stb, SearchTextBox.FileNameProprety);

ValidationError validationError =
    new ValidationError(new ExceptionValidationRule(), bindingExpression);

Validation.MarkInvalid(bindingExpressionBase, validationError);

ControlTemplate ct = this.Resources["validationErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
```

When I do this, I get the default behavior when there's no text inserted (that's my error case). The red box around the text box. What I want now is to use a custom Adorner Layout and I build it on XAML

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="validationErrorTemplate" x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid Width="12" Height="12">
                <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" 
                    Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"></Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Heavy" 
                    FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    X
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontWeight="12" Margin="2,0,0,2" 
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, 
                   Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But when I try to set the ErrorTemplate:

```
Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);
```

I don't get any error validation, not even the default template.

Am I missing something?

Comment: when you set breakpoint on `Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);` does `ct` have value or `ct` is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do

```
ControlTemplate ct = this.Resources["validationErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);
```

and there is no even default error template, it is likely that `ct` is null

make sure that "validationErrorTemplate" is stored in Window (`this`) resources. if template stored somewhere in resources, it can found by `FindResource` method

```
ControlTemplate ct = stb.FindResource("validationErrorTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right that `SearchTextBox` is inherited from `TextBox`?
Then change binding to this:

```
stb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindingStb);
```

**Update:**

```
ControlTemplate ct = FindResource("validationErrorTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. And what about the 

Validation.SetErrorTemplate(stb, ct);